Implementation of László Babai's Graph Isomorphism Algorithm
Has anyone (that we know of) ever actually implemented László Babai's algorithm for graph isomorphism in quasipolynomial time? If not, would such a thing even be possible/feasible?

Not that I know of. Why though, what are you looking for?

Honestly it was just a question that came to mind when watching the presentation he gave on the algorithm. I'm aware that there probably aren't any practical applications for it.
